# Mysql and make cumulative count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a clients mysql table and I´d like to get a cumulatie count of clients grouped by month-year.

I have tried the next, but no look:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datacad,'%m-%y') AS month-year, count(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS cumulative_count
FROM clients;

clients
-------
id datacad
1  2001-10-10
2  2001-10-11
3  2002-11-12
4  2001-12-14
5  2003-12-15
6  2003-12-16
7  2003-12-17

//required result
month-year  cumulative_count
----------------------------
10-2001     3
11-2002     4
12-2003     10
```

Additional Info:
When I use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datacad,'%m-%y') AS label, count(*) as total FROM clients
GROUP BY label 
order by datacad
```

I get:

```
label,total
03-2011,1
04-2011,1268
05-2011,1365
06-2011,1244
07-2011,1102
08-2011,315
02-2013,1
03-2013,1
03-2014,1
06-2014,1
07-2014,1
01-2017,1
02-2017,1
01-2018,4
05-2018,2
08-2018,1
09-2019,1
04-2020,3
06-2020,1
```

But when I use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datacad,'%m-%y') AS month_year, 
       SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS cumulative_count
FROM clients
GROUP BY month_year
ORDER BY MIN(datacad);
```

I get:

```
month_year,cumulative_count
03-11,1271
04-11,1268
05-11,2636
06-11,3880
07-11,4982
08-11,5297
02-13,5298
03-13,5299
03-14,5300
06-14,5301
07-14,5302
01-17,5303
02-17,5304
01-18,5308
05-18,1270
08-18,5309
09-19,5310
04-20,5313
06-20,5314
```

The results from both don´t match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` and to `SUM()` the counts for a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datacad,'%m-%y') AS month_year, 
       SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(datacad)) AS cumulative_count
FROM clients
GROUP BY month_year
ORDER BY MIN(datacad);
```

I also assume you want the data in date order, so I added an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I think you need `OVER (ORDER BY MIN(datacad))`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff please, I edited my post with yor tip. As you can see the results are not matching.

Comment: @ Paul Spiegel   You are sure. Thank you.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Please make the fix suggested by Paul. Then, I can accept your answer.